# OpenGL: Render one or multiple parts of a 3D-Model using one VAO(LWJGL)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, vao

i'm currently working on a LWJGL-program that displays an .obj model with it's textures and materials(render materials not added yet, but doesn't matter for this question). Loading the files and store theire data is no problem - in the end i have a WaveFrontObject.class (As posted below) that contains all the required information about my model including a List of it's single parts/groups. Also rendering them using glVertex3f(),glTextureCoord2f() and glNormal3f() works great. But since some of the models get pretty big(8MB or more) i want to make my rendering algorythm more efficient using VAOs and VBOs.

My problem is, that i wanna render one, all or a custom set of modelparts/groupobjects and apply a custom translation/rotation&scale to them.
To keep it clean and simple i want to use only one VAO per entity. So i somehow need to add/remove some parts of my vertices-VBO & indicesVBO or at least somehow decide which parts of my model should actually be rendered.
What is the best way of doing this?

**This is what i have so far** - Sorry if there are some unnecessary code parts, i tried out many things but it didn't work so i decided to come here and ask:

WaveFrontObject.class (The Main OBJLoader&OBJModel.class):

```
    package objmodels;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

import Toolbox.FileUtils;
import program.RLMEditor;
import shaders.StaticShader;
import textures.ModelTexture;

public class WaveFrontObject {

    private String fileName;

    public List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
    public List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
    public List<Vector2f> textureCoordinates = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
    public List<GroupObject> groupObjects = new ArrayList<GroupObject>();

    private GroupObject currentGroupObject = null;

    public int textureID;
    public boolean loadedTexture = false;

    public File texture;

    public int numLines;

    public RLMEditor program;

    public WaveFrontObject(File objFile,RLMEditor parent, boolean transferProgress) {
        this.textureID = ModelTexture.getStandardModel().getTextureID();
        this.fileName = objFile.getPath();
        this.program = parent;
        if (isValidOBJFile(objFile)) {
            loadOBJModel(objFile, transferProgress);
        }
    }

    public WaveFrontObject(File objFile) {
        this.textureID = ModelTexture.getStandardModel().getTextureID();
        this.fileName = objFile.getPath();
        if (isValidOBJFile(objFile)) {
            loadOBJModel(objFile, false);
        }
    }

    private void loadOBJModel(File objFile, boolean transferProgress) {
        if (transferProgress)
            try {
                //program.loadingProgress = new FrameProgressBar(numLines);
                //program.loadingProgress.setVisible(true);
                numLines = FileUtils.countLines(objFile.getPath());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        try {
            FileReader fileReader;
            fileReader = new FileReader(objFile);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String line = null;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineCount++;
                if (transferProgress) {
                       // program.loadingProgress.addStep(1);
                }
                if (line.startsWith("#") || line.isEmpty()) {
                } else if (line.startsWith("v ")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    Vector3f vertex = parseVertex(line.split(" "));
                    vertices.add(vertex);
                } else if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                    Vector3f normal = parseNormal(line.split(" "));
                    normals.add(normal);
                } else if (line.startsWith("vt ")) {
                    Vector2f texture = parseTexture(line.split(" "));
                    textureCoordinates.add(texture);
                } else if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                    if (currentGroupObject == null) {
                        currentGroupObject = new GroupObject("default");
                    }

                    Face face = parseFace(line, lineCount);

                    if (face != null) {
                        currentGroupObject.faces.add(face);
                    }
                } else if (line.startsWith("o ") || line.startsWith("g ")) {
                    GroupObject group = parseGroupObject(line, lineCount);

                    if (group != null) {
                        if (currentGroupObject != null) {
                            groupObjects.add(currentGroupObject);
                        }
                    }

                    currentGroupObject = group;
                    currentGroupObject.validate();
                    if(canAddGroupObject(currentGroupObject)){
                        groupObjects.add(currentGroupObject);
                    }else
                    System.out.println("The GroupObject '"+currentGroupObject.name+"' was already loaded!");
                }

            }
            //Parsing textureCoords to shader

            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("[FILENAME ERROR] The following File could not be found: " + fileName + "!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("[IO ERROR] FileReader for file: " + fileName + " could not be created!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean canAddGroupObject(GroupObject currentGroupObject) {
        for(GroupObject groupObject:groupObjects){
            if(groupObject.name.equalsIgnoreCase(currentGroupObject.name)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void renderAll(StaticShader shader) {
        if (currentGroupObject != null) {
            //GL11.glBegin(currentGroupObject.drawingMode);
        } else {
            //GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
        }
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        renderAllObjects(shader);
        //GL11.glEnd();
    }

    private void renderAllObjects(StaticShader shader) {
        for (GroupObject object : groupObjects) {
            object.render(shader);
        }
    }

    public void renderOnly(String... groupNames) {
        for (GroupObject groupObject : groupObjects) {
            for (String groupName : groupNames) {
                if (groupName.equalsIgnoreCase(groupObject.name)) {
                    renderObject(groupObject, program.window.shader);
                    //groupObject.render(program.window.shader);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void renderObject(GroupObject groupObject, StaticShader shader) {
             // Bind to the VAO that has all the information about the vertices
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(groupObject.vaoID);
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            // Bind to the index VBO that has all the information about the order of the vertices
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, groupObject.vboiID);

            // Draw the vertices
            GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, groupObject.getNumVertices());

            // Put everything back to default (deselect)
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void renderPart(String partName) {
        for (GroupObject groupObject : groupObjects) {
            if (partName.equalsIgnoreCase(groupObject.name)) {
                System.out.println("Rendering " + groupObject.name);
                groupObject.render(program.window.shader);
            }
        }
    }

    private GroupObject parseGroupObject(String line, int lineCount) {
        GroupObject group = null;

        if (isValidGroupObjectLine(line)) {
            String trimmedLine = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") + 1);

            if (trimmedLine.length() > 0) {
                group = new GroupObject(trimmedLine);
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("[OBJ FORMAT ERROR]");
            System.out.print("Parser was unable to read line number " + lineCount + "!");
        }

        return group;
    }

    private boolean isValidGroupObjectLine(String line) {
        return line.split(" ").length == 2;
    }

    private Face parseFace(String line, int lineCount) {
        Face face = null;
        String[] faceVertices = line.split(" ");
        String[] subTokens = null;
        if (faceVertices.length == 4) {
            currentGroupObject.drawingMode = GL11.GL_TRIANGLES;
            face = new Face();
            face.vertices = new Vector3f[faceVertices.length - 1];
            face.vertexNormals = new Vector3f[faceVertices.length - 1];
            face.textureCoords = new Vector2f[faceVertices.length - 1];

            for (int i = 1; i < faceVertices.length; i++) {
                subTokens = faceVertices[i].split("/");

                int currentVertexPointer = Integer.parseInt(subTokens[0]);
                face.indices.add(currentVertexPointer);

                face.vertices[i - 1] = vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(subTokens[0]) - 1);
                face.textureCoords[i - 1] = textureCoordinates.get(Integer.parseInt(subTokens[1]) - 1);
                face.vertexNormals[i - 1] = normals.get(Integer.parseInt(subTokens[2]) - 1);
            }

            face.faceNormal = face.calculateFaceNormal();

        }

        if (faceVertices.length == 5) {
            currentGroupObject.drawingMode = GL11.GL_QUADS;
            System.err.println("[OBJ FORMAT ERROR]");
            System.out.print("The .obj parser can currently only load models with triangulated faces!");
        }

        return face;
    }

    private Vector2f parseTexture(String[] textureData) {
        Vector2f texture = new Vector2f(Float.parseFloat(textureData[1]), Float.parseFloat(textureData[2]));
        return texture;
    }

    private Vector3f parseNormal(String[] normalData) {
        Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(normalData[1]), Float.parseFloat(normalData[2]),
                Float.parseFloat(normalData[3]));
        return normal;
    }

    private Vector3f parseVertex(String[] vertexData) {
        Vector3f vertex = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(vertexData[1]), Float.parseFloat(vertexData[2]),
                Float.parseFloat(vertexData[3]));
        return vertex;
    }

    private boolean isValidVertex(String[] vertexData) {
        return vertexData.length == 4;
    }

    private boolean isValidNormal(String[] normalData) {
        return normalData.length == 4;
    }

    private boolean isValidTexture(String[] textureData) {
        return textureData.length == 4;
    }

    private boolean isValidOBJFile(File objfile) {

        return objfile.getName().endsWith(".obj") || objfile.getName().endsWith(".OBJ");
    }

    public File getFileLocation() {
        return new File(fileName);
    }

    public void bindTexture(File textureFile) {
        Texture texture = null;
        try {
            texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("png", new FileInputStream(textureFile));
            this.textureID = texture.getTextureID();
            this.texture = textureFile;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public float[] getVertexArray(){
        float[] verticesArray = new float[vertices.size()*3];
        for(int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++){
            verticesArray[i*3]=vertices.get(i).x;
            verticesArray[i*3+1]=vertices.get(i).y;
            verticesArray[i*3+2]=vertices.get(i).z;

        }

        return verticesArray;
    }

    public float[] getTextureArray(){
        float[] texturesArray = new float[textureCoordinates.size()*2];
        for(int i = 0; i<textureCoordinates.size(); i++){
            texturesArray[i*2]=textureCoordinates.get(i).x;
            texturesArray[i*2+1]=textureCoordinates.get(i).y;

        }
        return texturesArray;
    }

    public void cleanUp(){
        for(GroupObject groupObject:groupObjects){
            groupObject.cleanUp();
        }
    }

}
```

**GroupObject.class** - Containing all faces from a single modelpart, it's name and the glDrawingMode (currently this can only be GL11.GL_TRIANGLES):

```
    package objmodels;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import shaders.StaticShader;

    public class GroupObject {
        public int vaoID;
        public int vboID;
        public int vboiID;

        private boolean isValid; //Used to set the vertex-&indicesArray only once 
        public String name;
        public List<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();
        public int drawingMode;
        private FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
        private IntBuffer indicesBuffer;
        private int numIndices;

        public GroupObject(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void prepareRendering(){
            vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

            // Create a new VBO for the indices and select it (bind)
            vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
            GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            // Put the VBO in the attributes list at index 0
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            // Deselect (bind to 0) the VBO
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

            // Deselect (bind to 0) the VAO
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

            vboiID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiID);
            GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            // Deselect (bind to 0) the VBO
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        }

        public void render(StaticShader shader) {
             // Bind to the VAO that has all the information about the vertices
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            // Bind to the index VBO that has all the information about the order of the vertices
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboiID);

            // Draw the vertices
            GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, getNumVertices());

            // Put everything back to default (deselect)
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        }

        public void cleanUp(){
            // Disable the VBO index from the VAO attributes list
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

            // Delete the vertex VBO
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vboID);

            // Delete the index VBO
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vboiID);

            // Delete the VAO
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
            GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoID);
        }

        public void renderFaces(StaticShader shader) {
            if (faces.size() > 0) {
                for (Face face : faces) {
                    face.addFaceForRender(shader);
                }
            }
        }

        public void validate() {
            this.isValid=true;
            this.verticesBuffer = getVertexBuffer();
            this.indicesBuffer = getIndicesBuffer();
        }

        public FloatBuffer getVertexBuffer() {
            float[] verticesArray = new float[getNumVertices()];
            for (int facePointer = 0; facePointer < faces.size(); facePointer++) {
                Face face = faces.get(facePointer);
                for (Vector3f faceVertex : face.vertices) {
                    verticesArray[facePointer] = faceVertex.x;
                    verticesArray[facePointer + 1] = faceVertex.y;
                    verticesArray[facePointer + 2] = faceVertex.z;
                }
            }

            FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(verticesArray.length);
            verticesBuffer.put(verticesArray);
            verticesBuffer.flip();

            return verticesBuffer;
        }

        public IntBuffer getIndicesBuffer() {
            List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int facePointer = 0; facePointer < faces.size(); facePointer++) {
                Face face = faces.get(facePointer);
                int[] indicesArray = face.getIndicesArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < indicesArray.length; i++) {
                    indices.add(indicesArray[i]);
                    numIndices++;
                }
            }

            int[] indicesArray = new int[indices.size()];
            for (int index = 0; index < indices.size(); index++) {
                indicesArray[index] = indices.get(index);
            }

            IntBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indicesArray.length);
            indicesBuffer.put(indicesArray);
            indicesBuffer.flip();

            return indicesBuffer;
        }

        public int getNumVertices() {
            int number = 0;
            for (Face face : faces) {
                number += face.getNumVertices();
            }
            return number;
        }

    }
```

**Face.class**-Holding the information about a single Face(Vertices,Normals&Texturecoords):

```
    package objmodels;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector2f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import shaders.StaticShader;

public class Face {

    public Vector3f[] vertices;
    public Vector3f[] vertexNormals;
    public Vector2f[] textureCoords;

    public Vector3f faceNormal;
    public List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Face() {
        this.vertices = new Vector3f[3];
        this.vertexNormals = new Vector3f[3];
        this.textureCoords = new Vector2f[3];
    }

    public Face(Vector3f[] vertices, Vector3f[] vertexNormals, Vector2f[] textureCoords) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.vertexNormals = vertexNormals;
        this.textureCoords = textureCoords;
        this.faceNormal = calculateFaceNormal();
    }

    public void setVertex(int index, Vector3f vertex, Vector3f normal, Vector2f textureCoords) {
        this.vertices[index] = vertex;
        this.vertexNormals[index] = normal;
        this.textureCoords[index] = textureCoords;
    }

    public Vector3f calculateFaceNormal() {
        Vector3f v1 = new Vector3f(vertices[1].x - vertices[0].x, vertices[1].y - vertices[0].y,
                vertices[1].z - vertices[0].z);
        Vector3f v2 = new Vector3f(vertices[2].x - vertices[0].x, vertices[2].y - vertices[0].y,
                vertices[2].z - vertices[0].z);
        Vector3f normalVector = null;

        normalVector = (Vector3f) Vector3f.cross(v1, v2, normalVector).normalise();

        return new Vector3f((float) normalVector.x, (float) normalVector.y, (float) normalVector.z);
    }

    public void addFaceForRender(StaticShader shader) {
        Vector3f normal = calculateFaceNormal();
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
            {
                // int textureCoordsLocation =
                // GL20.glGetAttribLocation(shader.programID, "textureCoords");
                Vector3f vertex = vertices[i];
                Vector2f textureCoord = textureCoords[i];
                // GL20.glVertexAttrib2f(textureCoordsLocation, textureCoord.x,
                // textureCoord.y);
                GL11.glTexCoord2f(textureCoord.x, textureCoord.y);
                GL11.glVertex3d(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
                GL11.glNormal3d(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getNumVertices() {
        return vertices.length;
    }

    public int[] getIndicesArray() {
        int[] indicesArray = new int[indices.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++) {
            indicesArray[i]=indices.get(i);
        }
        return indicesArray;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advice - ItsAMysterious

Comment: You can use one VAO, and have different offsets into the VAO for each group of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you posted too much code (~570 lines, wow!) so I can't read it all.  But you are solving a very common problem, and I can give you the general solution.

The problem is, "I want to draw different models using one shared VAO."  This is actually a lot easier than it sounds.  You can simply concatenate all of your models into the same VBOs, and then when you call `glDrawElements()` or `glDrawArrays()`, you specify which part of the array you want to use (using `glDrawElementsBaseVertex()` instead of `glDrawElements()`, if necessary).

For example, let's say we have models A, B, and C.  Let's say that model A has 1000 vertexes, model B has 500, and model C has 750.

First, concatenate all the vertex data into one VBO, and use one VAO for everything.  Now you can call:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,    0, 1000); // model A
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 1000,  500); // model B
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 1500,  750); // model C
```

If you are using `glDrawElements()`, you have two choices.

- You can pass ranges to `glDrawElements()`, and have the index array point into the combined VAO, or
- You can pass ranges to `glDrawElementsBaseVertex()`, and have the index array be relative to the first vertex in each model.

Either way, it's common a common technique to reduce the number of state changes.  Another alternative is to use `glBindVertexBuffer()`, specifying a different offset into your VBO each time, but this is only in core as of 4.3 and it's a bit more flexible than you need.

Comment: OMG - Thank you so much! Im gonna test this out right now!

Comment: Um one general question - my program causes my computer to not respond anymore. Is there a severe difference between glDrawElements and glDrawArrays appart from the fact that you need indices for glDrawElements?

Comment: @ItsAMysterious: Not a big difference.  There can be problems, however, if your indexes are out of range.

Comment: Ah okay - so i do not need to have indices if i don't wanna use glDrawElements right?

Comment: Right.  If you have indexes, you use `glDrawElements()`.  If you don't, you use `glDrawArrays()`, which is the same thing as calling `glDrawElements()` with an index array of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: Thank you! Now - using glVertexAttribArray() i can pass over values to my shader right?

Comment: You mean `glVertexAttribPointer()`? Yes.

Comment: Oh - my fault - surely that was meant to be AttribPointer. Okay great :P